# Blog PDO connection error

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, blogs

So I'm getting this error,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\Blog\verwerk.php on line 14.

This is my script

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Desir
 * Date: 10-5-2017
 * Time: 11:55
 */

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "-";

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=blog", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

I can't figure out a way to get it working been trying loads of stuff.
Would be nice if someone could actually help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: This code does not have the said parse error

Comment: Well, tell me why I'm getting it then?

Comment: some where you try to use `$conn` variable? show us that code along with the above code

Comment: Is this really the whole code? As it is now, there are no errors except a failing DB connection, but that would trigger the `catch` block.

Comment: The script I added above is the only script where I used this variable

Comment: I also got a script for adding a post, deleting and editing one. I also have an index.php

Comment: @KimAllenboyNijenhuis  is the above code belong to `verwerk.php`? if no then show `verwerk.php` page code.don't remove this one ,just add `verwerk.php` page code in your question

Comment: Usually errors like this are because you left out `;` on the line before the error.

Comment: The code above is my verwerk.php (My connection)

Comment: the problem is with your password for the mysql. i tested this code with my  password which is characters and numbers, and it was connected successfully

Comment: @Exprator well this is weird, because I use the same password for logging in on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: i know, but from script special characters create problem, just change the password and give it a try

Comment: Well I fixed it by removing the try and catch, only I'm getting a different error at the moment.

Comment: And the new error is...?

Comment: I already fixed it, thanks for helping tho, really appreciate your time.